# Is it possible to clone others' repository in Github to be under my account?

Tags: github

In GitHub, can I clone a repository of someone else to be under my account?

If yes, when the other's repository is privately shared with me, can I also make my clone private to myself only?

Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what a "fork" is.

Comment: Yep, its called a Fork. On the top right of a github projectPage there is a button where you can Fork the repository, which is basically a copy of that repository under your name/account.

Comment: Thanks. @n247s. Does a repository at github track which accounts have forked it to where?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart when the other's repository is privately shared with me, can I also make my clone private to myself only, not to anyone else including the other?

Comment: @Tim I believe it does keep track indeed(there is a fork counter near the fork button). And yes you can make any repository/fork private, as long as you have that privalige! If you dont wanna pay for it, I suggest using bitbucket instead.

Comment: @n247s do you mean a github repository only track the number of clones and not who have cloned it where?

Comment: @tim best way is to try and find out  :) you would save more time that way .

Comment: It does both, but Im not sure if the accounts who forked are vissible to the repository owner only or if its public.

Comment: @n247s your first comment provides an answer to the question.  Jonathon Reinhart started it off, but you gave the full story.  The rest of your comments add details to it.  If you make it into an answer, people can upvote it.  Not that you need the points.